# Phusion Passenger stand-alone error pid lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to debug a Bitnami Rails stack.  I thought if I ran Passenger in stand-alone that I could tell if it's an Apache issue.

I ran this SSH command:

```
$ passenger start
```

This is part of the console:

```
Installing Phusion Passenger Standalone...
[*********************************************] Copying files...
All done!

Stopping web server.../opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-1.0.0/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `initialize': Permission denied - /opt/bitnami/passenger.3000.pid.lock (Errno::EACCES)
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks!